# What is $2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$................. (up to?

Tags: factorial, infinity

A few days back a question came to my mind

> What is the value of $2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!....$ (up to infinity)?

I feel it is 2, but one of my friends said that we can't say that for infinity.

I know it comes out to be 2 for any finite value.

But what about infinity?

Comment: Probably you are getting a warning because the system does not want excessive use of exclamation marks; though in this case it is acceptable.

Comment: what now i get is that you can say it 2 for ---->infinity but not exactly for infinity

Comment: Notation is just notation. You can't write down all those exclamation marks, just like you can't write out in full what $\ldots$ means in $1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + \ldots$, but it is a convenient and well-established tradition to use shorthands of various kinds to avoid giving the details of a recursive definition. So providing you know how to give the detailed formal definition if asked and providing what you write is clear to your readers, use the notation that works for you.

Comment: I don't know a well-established meaning or definition for exclamation points extending indefinitely to the right "up to infinity".  I have therefore voted to close as "unclear what you are asking".  Note that [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) $k!!$ has a commonly used meaning/definition, which is *not* the same as $(k!)!$.

Comment: @hardmath Did you really vote to close this question on those grounds? I'm sad...

Comment: @hardmath Feel free to tag the question as "soft-question" but don't vote to close it ... you could even edit the question to read "how do I make sense of this expression, and what would its value be?" Edit: apologies for the "hard-nosed" pun :P

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee:  Please edit the Question (or encourage the OP to do so) if you know what the meaning of the notation is.  Yash's Comment above is a hint, but comments only mitigate the need to have good Questions.

Comment: @hardmath: you say the expression is "undefined", but I think that just reflects a view of yours on mathematical notation. What do you mean by "undefined" here?

Comment: @RobArthan:  I refer to your earlier Comment, where the justification for using "a convenient... shorthand" is conditioned on (1) knowing how to give the detailed formal definition if asked and (2) providing what you write is clear to your readers.  My lack of understanding is just that, and I will happily undo my vote-to-close if your conditions can be fulfilled.

Comment: The OP can write $x!!!\ldots$ (with an accompanying explanation) to mean the limit as $n$ tends to $\infty$ of $x!!!\ldots!$ with $n$ exclamation marks (if that limit exists) and think of that bit of syntax as meaning $x$ followed by infinitely many exclamation marks. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this as a notational device. I (and others) have given the formal definition and whether the notation is clear (or useful) to a reader will depend on how the OP plans to use the notation (I can't see much use for it myself, but I defend his or her rights to use it if they want to).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To be formal, you are perfectly entitled to define a sequence of numbers $s_n$ such that:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
s_0 &=& 2 \\
s_{n+1} &=& s_n!
\end{array}
$$
so that $s_n = 2! \ldots !$ with $n$ exclamation marks. But then, because $2! = 2$, you can prove by induction that $s_n = 2$ for all $n$ and this means $s_n$ tends to the limit $2$ as $n$ tends to infinity. I don't think it is harmful to think of this limit informally as $2!!!\ldots$ with a countable infinity of exclamation marks.

Comment: I disagree. It is particularly harmful to think about this as countably infinite number of factorials, as it lends itself to an extension that these things are "usually working out". It's easier to teach people to work correctly from the get go, and not weep for their mistakes later on.

Comment: Good answer, just wondering why you specify a "countable" infinity, what problems are there with applying induction with uncountable infinity?

Comment: @Siwel: I wrote "countable" to keep things simple for the OP.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am not a professional teacher, but I **did** take care to give the formal explanation first. I don't see this as a question of "working correctly" but as one of thinking of useful (or at least tolerably acceptable) analogies between the finite and the infinite  (no worse than the usual way we talk about sums and products of infinite sequences).

Comment: Does induction work for when treating with limits? I thought that was false.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I have no idea what you mean by "Does induction work with limits". In the case in point here, you use induction to prove that a sequence is constant and that tells you all you need to know about the limit.

Comment: I mean this: by induction I could prove something like $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i, A_i=\{i\in \Bbb N\}$ is finite for all natural $n$, however if we take the limit as $n\to +\infty$ the previous result isn't true. Why is it true here?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I am sorry but your comment makes no sense. What is $A_i$? What do you mean by "the previous result"?

Comment: Hmm I defined $A_i$ up there: $A_i=\{i \in \Bbb N\}$. The previous result refers to the fact that the set $\cup _{i=1}^nA_i$ is finite $forall n \in \Bbb N$ which is a fact that's provable by induction.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I don't think you are using standard notations. To check, could you please list the members of $A_2$ and$A_3$?

Comment: Yes. $A_2=\{2\}, A_3=\{3\}$. The union: $\cup_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i$ is thus, $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: well your first comment " does induction work when treating with limits. I thought that was false" is unsubstantiated.

Comment: What do you mean? I showed what I claimed: $\cup_{i\in \Bbb N} A_i=\lim_{i \to +\infty}\cup_i^n A_i=\Bbb N$...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: the formula you wrote doesn't make sense. What's $n$? What process are you using to form limits of sets of natural numbers?

Answer (score 10):

You have to formally state what an infinite number of factorials is meant to be. You could define a sequence by:
$$\begin{align*}a_0 &= 2 \\ a_n &= a_{n - 1}! \qquad \text{ for } n > 1\end{align*}$$

This means for example:
$$a_3 = a_2! = a_1 !! = a_0 !!! \\ a_4 = a_3! = a_2!! = a_1 !!! = a_0 !!!! \\ \ldots$$

The limit of $a_n$ is what we might understand as the value of "$a_0!!!\ldots$".

It is easy to see that $a_n = 2$ for all $n$, so the limit of $a_n$ is $2$. Therefore the term "$2!!!!\ldots$" can be interpreted as $2$.

Answer (score 5):

$2!$ is just $2$. So doing $2!...!$ finitely many times produces $2$ as well.To say $2!...!$ up to infinity doesn't really make sense. What you can ask is: what is the limit of $b_n$ as $n\to \infty$, where $b_1 = 2$ and $b_n = b_{n-1}!$ for each $n$? The answer is $2$, since $(b_n)$ is a constant sequence.

Answer (score 3):

It is not as simple as some people are arguing! Consider a sequence $s_n=(2+1/n)!![n-{\rm times}]!!$ one can also say the limit of this sequence is $2!!![{\rm infinitely\; many}]$, however the result, I am sure, is divergent and is not $2$. Basically one can get any result by changing the definition.

Please give an argument before downvoting. 
(in case you don't know factorial is perfectly defined for non-integer values by $x!=\Gamma(1+x)$

Let me specify the most general definition: let $t_n$ is a convergent to $2$ sequence, then $$2!!!\dots\equiv \lim_{n\to\infty} t_n ![n-{\rm times}]$$
Conjecture (may be wrong) would be then that $2!!!\dots \ge 2$

Comment: I'm also curious as to why this is being downvoted. It seems like a perfectly valid point.

Comment: Perhaps it is being downvoted because instead of providing an Answer, the point is being made that the Question is not well posed.  One can agree with the latter point without agreeing with this use of the Answer box. (I am not a downvoter here.)

Comment: @hardmath That seems like the only correct way to respond to this question, though. It's just like when people ask about $0^0$, or $0.000...01$; the thing to do is explain how to correctly use mathematical notation. Pretending that there is an answer (as some have done) is simply wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is that OP's expression is clearly about lots of factorials and about the number $2$. Introducing a sequence that converges to $2$ is not suggested by OPs expression. That's a complication you are introducing. I mean, no one thinks of $0+0+0+\cdots$ as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$ just because $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Your example is misleading, I disagree. The correct analog would be rather $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ than what you said. Or if you want $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n)/(2/n)$ as a resolution of $0/0$ ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for proper generalisation and the implications thereof!

Comment: So you conflate the sequence  $a_n = (1 + 1/n)^n$  with $b_n = 1^n$. That doesn't look good to me.

Comment: in your case $1^\infty = e^{0*\infty}$ is as ambiguous as $0\times \infty$ or $0/0$, so yes

Comment: This would only be a problem if the gamma function were not continuous.  It is, so it interchanges limits just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I guess it will just be 2.

We can continue to add faculty to the number - but the value of the faculty will remain 1; so we'll keep on adding ()*1.

(((((((2*1)*1)*1)*1)*1)*1)*1)*1...*1

Comment: can we say that for infinity?

Comment: @YashMalik How would you define $2\underbrace{!!\cdots}_\infty$ if not as $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\underbrace{!!\cdots !}_n$?

Comment: "faculty"???? Is this meant to be "factorial"?

Comment: @AlexM. Probably a German speaker, "factorial = Fakultät".

Comment: @DanielFischer or a Dutch speaker, "factorial = faculteit" ;-)

Comment: @barto And probably some other not too unrelated languages.

Answer (score 2):

Let us define $S=2!!!!!!!...$ Now,
$$
S! = (2!!!!\dots)! = S\\
S=S!\\
S\in {1,2}
$$

Comment: Your answer gives the impression that $1$ is a plausible value. Just because $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ are solutions to $x^2 - 4 = 0$, should I worry about whether $2 = -2$?

Comment: I love these kinds of arguments so much that I feel like there must be some way to eliminate one of the values.

Answer (score 2):

Just write $a_n:=2!\cdots!$ with $n$ exclamation marks. You want to compute $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n$. But you can easily show by induction that $a_n=2\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$, hence you're searching the limit of a constant sequence.